# fly.io ENV available in Dockerfile

Tags: fly

Im trying to access env variables that are specified in the fly.toml file in the Dockerfile when running `flyctrl deploy` however they are always showing as empty strings. Am i doing something wrong here?

```ini
[env]
  API = "ABC"
```

```
ARG API
ENV API $API
RUN echo $API // prints Run echo
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this can be done with '[build.args]'

```ini
[build.args]
  API = "ABCD"
```